# when i run this command "$ docker build --pull -t e45 . " in file .gitlab-ci.yml i get error

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, devops, gitlab-ci-runner

gitlab-runner gives error:
`ERROR: error during connect: Get "http://docker:2375/_ping": dial tcp: lookup docker on 127.0.0.53:53: server misbehaving`

when it tries to run command `docker build --pull -t my-image` 
[this is my gitlab-ci.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZg3E.png)

[this my pipeline log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCaeq.png)

I was expecting gitlab-runner to create the image without problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to map the host docker sockets to to the runner sockets by adding a volume to the GitLab runner config file

gitlab-runner config file path in your host:

/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml

add these lines

```
privileged = true
volumes = ["/cache","/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"]
```